# El diseño del switch se aplica en los primeros elementos de la tabla

Tags: javascript, ajax, bootstrap, codeigniter

Hola buenos días tengo problemas con mis switches ya que al darle clic al paginador para ir a la siguiente pagina los switches pierden su diseño. La tabla la estoy llenado con Ajax y después coloco el javascript del plugin del swich.

¿Tienen alguna idea porque solamente el switch se aplica en los primeros elementos de la tabla?

Les comparto mi código

Tabla

```js
function getAlumnosRadiusAjax() {

    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo base_url('Radius/getAlumnosRadiusAjax')?>",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          var html = '';
          var btn_switch = '';
          var contador = 1;

          var filas = data.length;
          for (i = 0 ; i < filas; i++){

            if (data[i].wifi_status == "enabled") {
              btn_switch = "<input type='checkbox' name='switch-wifi-status' onclick='mensajePrueba();' id='switch-wifi-status' checked data-bootstrap-switch>";
            } else {
              btn_switch = "<input type='checkbox' name='switch-wifi-status' id='switch-wifi-status' checked data-bootstrap-switch>";
            }

            html += `<tr>
                      <td>${contador}</td>
                      <td>${data[i].idPerson}</td>
                      <td>${data[i].name}</td>
                      <td>${data[i].instEmail}</td>
                      <td>${data[i].carrer}</td>
                      <td>${data[i].type}</td>
                      <td>
                        ${btn_switch}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" title="Autorizar" onclick="updateAlumnosRadiusAjax('${data[i].enrollment}');"><i class="fas fa-unlock"></i></a>
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" title="Clave" onclick="message_success('${data[i].value}');"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></a>
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" title="Generar contraseña"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></a>
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" title="Cambiar contraseña email"><i class="fas fa-unlock-alt"></i></a>
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" title="Enviar mail"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i></a>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>`; 

            contador++;
          }
          $('#tbody-radius').html(html); //inserto los registros a la tabla
          $('#tabla_radius_alumnos').DataTable(); //activo e DataTables

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("algo salio mal");
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<section class="content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- /.row -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="card-title">DataTable with default features</h3> 
          </div>
          <!-- /.card-header -->
          <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0">
            <table id="tabla_radius_alumnos" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>#</th>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Nombre</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Carrera</th>
                  <th>Grupo</th>
                  <th>Estatus</th>
                  <th>Movimientos</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id="tbody-radius">

              </tbody>
              <tfoot>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Nombre</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Carrera</th>
                  <th>Grupo</th>
                  <th>Estatus</th>
                  <th>Movimientos</th>
              </tr>
              </tfoot>
            </table>
          </div>
          <!-- /.card-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</section>
```

Código nuevo fuera de mi función

```js
// Ejecutar hasta que se haya cargado el DOM
$(function() {
    // Inicializar el plugin sobre elementos específicos
    $("input[data-bootstrap-switch]").bootstrapSwitch();
    // Delegar evento
    $('#tbody-radius').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', 'input[data-bootstrap-switch]', function(event, state) {
        // Activar diseño de switch
        $("input[data-bootstrap-switch]").each(function(){
            $(this).bootstrapSwitch('state', $(this).prop('checked'));
        });
    });
});
```

> Resultado (chequen que solo aplica a los elementos de la pestaña 1 y a
> los de la pestaña 2 del paginador no)

[image: Aquí si aplica el diseño del switch]

[image: Aquì no aplica el diseño del switch]

¿En que parte de mi código debo de colocar el javascript del plugins switch?

Comment: Probablemente no es el lugar donde pones el código, sino cómo lo pones. Edita la pregunta y agrega el código que usas para activar el plugin.

Comment: El código ya esta en la pregunta, le agregue un comentario que dice "//Activo el diseño del switch"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Actualización 2:

Siguendo la recomendación en los comentarios, encontré que dataTables también tiene *hooks*:

```
  // Insertar registros
  $('#tbody-radius').html(html);
  // Activar DataTable
  $('#tabla_radius_alumnos').DataTable();
  // Escuchar evento DataTable
  $('#tabla_radius_alumnos').on('draw.dt', function () {
      // Inicializar plugin
      $("input[data-bootstrap-switch]").bootstrapSwitch();
      // Activar diseño de switch
      $("input[data-bootstrap-switch]").each(function(){
          $(this).bootstrapSwitch('state', $(this).prop('checked'));
      });
  });
```

Referencia: [Eventos dataTables](https://www.datatables.net/reference/event/)

### Actualización:

Los registros no existen hasta que los muestra `DataTable`, entonces intenta agregar un evento delegado:

```
// Ejecutar hasta que se haya cargado el DOM
$(function() {
    // Inicializar el plugin sobre elementos específicos
    $("input[data-bootstrap-switch]").bootstrapSwitch();
    // Delegar evento
    $('#tbody-radius').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', 'input[data-bootstrap-switch]', function(event, state) {
        // Activar diseño de switch
        $("input[data-bootstrap-switch]").each(function(){
            $(this).bootstrapSwitch('state', $(this).prop('checked'));
        });
    });
});
```

Según la documentación de jQuery para [on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

> Los eventos delegados tienen la ventaja de poder procesar eventos de elementos descendientes que fueron agregados al documento después de la carga inicial

Referencia de hook (evento) [switchChange.bootstrapSwitch](https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/09/01/hooking-the-onswitchchange-event-in-bootstrap-switch/)

**Nota:** Eliminé opciones que no han funcionado y dejé solo las que parecen ir mejor encaminadas.

Comment: al añadir la promesa me sale una leyenda en el navegador que dice "Una pagina web esta causando que tu navegador vaya lentamente" y se tarda demasiado que mejor le doy den detener a la leyenda para que detenga el proceso.

Comment: al dejar tanto datatables como el javascript del switch dentro de la promesa en ese orde solo cargan los registros de la primera pestaña del paginador, pero al poner primero el javascript del switch y debajo databales pero dentro de la promesa la pagina se tarda y ralentiza y mejor le doy detener, al dejar el javascript dentro de la promesa y el databables afuera igual se pone lenta y manda el mensaje y mejor detengo el proceso, pero al dejar datatables dentro de promesa y el javascript switch fuera de promesa igual solo se ve el switch en los primeros registros del paginador pestaña 1

Comment: sigue poniendo el diseño de switch unicamente en la primera pestaña del paginador

Comment: sigue igual, solo muestra en la primera pestaña

Comment: cuando agrego el console me imprime solamente los primero 10 registros

Comment: Tengo que poner el código actualizado abajo de $('#tbody-radius').html(html);???

Comment: Lo coloque abajo de estos elementos $('#tbody-radius').html(html); //inserto los registros a la tabla
          // Activar DataTable
          $('#tabla_radius_alumnos').DataTable();

Comment: No aplico el diseño en ningún registro

Comment: no se si lo estoy poniendo bien, pero unicamente me muestra el switch en los primeros registros

Comment: Ya coloque el código fuera de mi funcion javascript, modifique mi pregunta con los cambios que me dijiste, revisa si lo estoy haciendo bien. El resultado que obtuve fue que no me coloco el switch en ningún registro.

Comment: ¿Aún no lo has podido resolver?

Comment: No, aun sigue colocando el switch en los primeros registros.

Comment: @Triby ¿no existe algún evento que permita saber cuando se cambia de página y con ello ejecutar el cambio de los switchs nuevamente?

Comment: @JosueArriola, excelente sugerencia, esperemos que sea la solución.

Answer (score 1):

Por si aun no has podido resolver el problema. Datatables tiene un evento `page` que detecta el cambio de página, te muestro como integrarlo

```
$('#tbody-radius').html(html); //inserto los registros a la tabla
$('#tabla_radius_alumnos').DataTable(); //activo DataTables

// Agregas el listener para el cambio de página
$('#table_radius_alumnos').on( 'page.dt', function () {
    createToggle();
});

// Utiliza una función que puedas utilizar en diferentes eventos
// Eata vez por el estado inicial, despuea lo mandaras llamar en el listener anterior
createToggle();
```

En otro segmento del codigo agrega dicha función

```
function createToggle () {
    $("input[data-bootstrap-switch]").bootstrapSwitch();
    $('#tbody-radius').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', 'input[data-bootstrap-switch]', function(event, state) {
        // Activar diseño de switch
        $("input[data-bootstrap-switch]").each(function(){
            $(this).bootstrapSwitch('state', $(this).prop('checked'));
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: No se activa el diseño del switch, no se si soy yo quien lo esta haciendo mal, pero este error no lo logro solucionar

Comment: coloque un alert dentro del lister y cuando cambio de pagina no se activa.