# jQuery DataTables: estilo personalizado no carga a partir de la segunda pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy tratando de realizar una tabla con varias columnas con chexkbox, y a estos checkbox estoy tratando de darles un estilo de bootstrap Switch, en los primero 10 registros aparece  correctamente el checkbox con el estilo el problema esta en que a partir de la segunda pagina me muestra solo el checkbox sin estilo

**adjunto el codigo de la tabla para su ayuda**
**html**

```
<table id="table_Permisos"  class="table table-bordered table-striped" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead style="text-align: center;">
        <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>Grupo</th>
          <th>Opcion</th>
          <th>Estado</th>
          <th>Permiso Add</th>
          <th>Permiso Mod</th>     
          <th>Permiso View</th>     
          <th>Permiso Del</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody style="text-align: center;">
                      
     </tbody>
```

**js**

```
 $.ajax({
      url:"./../controller/permisocontroller.php",
      type:"POST",
      dataType:'json',
      data:{id:id},
      success:function(respuesta){    
      tb= $('#table_Permisos').DataTable( {
              "destroy": true,
               "data": respuesta,
                "processing": true,
                "responsive": true,
                "autoWidth": false,
                "ordering": false,
                "info": true,
                "select": false,
                "columns": [
                    { data: 'idsystemop' },
                    { data: 'group_interfaces' },
                    { data: 'title'},
                    { data: 'state'},
                ],
                "columnDefs": [{
                  "targets":[4,5,6,7],
                  "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                        var input = '';
                          if (type === 'display') 
                        {
                           if (meta.col === 4) {
                              input += '<input type="checkbox" id="permadd " name="permadd '+meta.row+ " "+ row.idsystemop+'"  data-bootstrap-switch data-off-color="danger" data-on-color="success"> ';
                         }else if (meta.col === 5){
                             input += '<input type="checkbox" id="permod" name="permod '+meta.row+ " "+ row.idsystemop+'" data-bootstrap-switch data-off-color="danger" data-on-color="success"> ';
                         }else if (meta.col === 6){
                          input += '<input type="checkbox" id="perview" name="perview '+meta.row+ " "+ row.idsystemop+'" data-bootstrap-switch data-off-color="danger" data-on-color="success"> ';
                         } else if (meta.col === 7){
                          input += '<input type="checkbox" id="permdelet" name="permdelet '+meta.row+ " "+ row.idsystemop+'" data-bootstrap-switch data-off-color="danger" data-on-color="success"> ';
                         } 
                            
                        }
                        return input;
                  }
                },

                ],
                // 'order': [[1, 'asc']]
              } 
            );
            
            $("input[data-bootstrap-switch]").each(function(){
              $(this).bootstrapSwitch('state', $(this).prop('checked'));
            }); 
        }
```

la tabla la cargo mediante un ajax anterior
de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/366226/el-dise%c3%b1o-del-switch-se-aplica-en-los-primeros-elementos-de-la-tabla/366243#366243), solo necesitas detectar cuando se actualice la tabla para aplicar el estilo.

Comment: le he hechado un vistazo, gracias me sirvio como referencia