# Tooltip bootstrap 4 en data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Estoy poniendo `tooltip` de bootstrap 4 en un data table iterado de la base de datos, pero solo me funciona en la primera página, en el resto no.

Esta es mi tabla:

```
<table id="tablaClientes" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="thnueva">#Fecha</th>
          <th class="thnueva">Nombre</th>
          <th class="thnueva center">Teléfono</th>
          <th class="thnueva center">Tipo</th>
          <th class="thnueva center">Marca</th>
          <th class="thnueva">Tecnología</th>
          <th class="thnueva center fixed" width="15"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
       <tbody>
           @foreach ($clientes as $clie)  
              <tr class="dato_tabla">
                 <td>{{ $clie->fecha_contacto }}</td>
                 <td>
                   <div class="siglas" style="letter-spacing: -1.95px;">
                      @php
                         echo str_limit($clie->name, 1, "");
                      @endphp 
                      @php
                         echo str_limit($clie->apellidos, 1, "");
                      @endphp    
                    </div>  
                                        
                    <div class="ayudaletr255">
                       {{ $clie->name }} {{ $clie->apellidos }} <br> 
                       <span class="spanEmail">{{ $clie->email }}</span><br>
                       <small class="colorSmall">{{$clie->centro}}</small>
                     </div>
                   </td>
                   <td class="center">{{$clie->telefono}}</td>
                   <td class="center">
                      @if ($clie->tipo_empresa == 0)
                         <span class="estadoClientes adminBG">Cliente final</span>
                      @else
                         <span class="estadoClientes adminBG">Distribuidor</span>
                       @endif
                    </td>
                    <td class="center">
                       @if ($clie->marca == 0)
                          <span class="estadoClientes depildiodo">Depildiodo</span>
                       @elseif ($clie->marca == 1)
                          <span class="estadoClientes apolo">Med.Apolo Médico</span>
                       @elseif ($clie->marca == 2)
                          <span class="estadoClientes apolo2">Med.Apolo Estética</span>
                       @endif
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ $clie->nombreEquipo }}</td>
                    <td class="center">
                        <button type="button" class="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{$clie->telefono}}" data-animation="false">
                                            <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i>
                        </button>
                        <a class="mydrop2a" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                           <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                        </a>    
                        <div class="dropdown-menu drop22" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                           <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('app.verClientePotencial', $clie->id) }}">
                        <li>
                           <i class="far fa-eye"></i> Ver cliente
                        </li>
                        </a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('app.editarClientePotencial', $clie->id) }}">
                          <li>
                            <i class="far fa-edit"></i> Editar cliente
                          </li>
                        </a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item borrar_potencial" href="javascript:void(0);" id="{{ $clie->id }}">
                           <li>
                            <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> Eliminar
                           </li>
                         </a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      </td>
                     </tr>
                 @endforeach
               </tbody>
</table>
```

Y par activar el `tooltip` hago lo siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
});
```

Comment: Necesitamos que proporciones un ejemplo mínimo verificable del problema, tu código no me funciona. Además no especificas que utilizas php, ni tampoco de que manera quieres solucionar el problema, si mediante php o jquery. Creo que si mejoras estos aspectos podrías recibir ayuda con mayor rapidez. Saludos

Comment: Necesitas usar los eventos de _DataTable_ y aplicar _tooltip_ al actualizar el contenido. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/366243/54039), te puede servir.

Comment: Hola y gracias por tu respuesta @Triby . Pero yo genero la tabla con php, no la voy actualizando por javascript ni nada. Entonces como meto un evento ahí?

Comment: Tú no la vas actualizando, pero _DataTable_ sí al hacer el cambio de página, por eso debes aplicar el _tooltip_ dentro del evento.

Comment: aha!!! ya lo comprendí y solucione! muchas gracias @Triby como siempre. `$('#tablaClientes').on( 'draw.dt', function () { $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();} );` Si quieres publica una respuesta y la marco.

Comment: No es necesaria la respuesta, porque creo que la pregunta puede considerarse duplicada de la otra.

Comment: Tienes razón! que hago borro la pregunta, o como está tu enlace a la otra pregunta la dejo?

Comment: Déjala como referencia, probablemente después la marquen como duplicada.